# Save messages with an input form in websocket node js and php

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, forms, websocket

Welcome all,
In my project I made a social network in PHP, and a chat using websocket with node.js

The problem I have it is I can not save the messages in my database because I can't get the messages from input form.

The server side have node.js (js only)
And client side accept js, and php (.php extension)

I tried to save messages inside server side but I can't because the project have the sessions of each user in php, so..

I tried to save messages inside client side which it's in .php extension,

The thing I tried it is to save the input where I write the message,

I will left the client side code:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["user"])){
  header("location:../login.php");
}
require "../config.php";
$conn = mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$passw,$database);
$user=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_SESSION["user"];
$q1 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM usuario2 WHERE Usuario = '".$user."'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q1)){
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $row['ID']);
}

$query1 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `chat1` WHERE id_em='$id' OR id_rec='$id'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query1)){
$row["id_em"];
}

$codroom=$_POST["user3"];

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <?php
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    ?>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.4/socket.io.js"></script>
    <title>Chat con nodejs + socket.io</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <style>
    h2 {
      margin-top: 20px;
    }
    .input-group-addon{
      background-color: rgb(2, 117, 216);
      color: #efefef;
    }
    #messages {
      padding: none;
    }
    .chat-window {
      height: 500px;
      border: 1px solid #cccccc;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      padding: 1rem;
      overflow-y: scroll;
    }
    .msg {
      margin-bottom: 1rem;
    }
.id{
    font-weight: bolder;
}

    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <h2>Websocket & Socket.io Chat</h2>
</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
     var socket = io.connect( 'http://localhost:1334' );

        $(function(){
            $("form").submit(function(){
                var mensaje = $("#msg").val();
                if(mensaje=='') return false;
                if(mensaje==' ') return false;
                //evento message en el server nodejs
                console.log(mensaje)

                socket.emit('message',mensaje);
                $("#msg").val('').focus();
                return false;
            });
            $("#channel").change(function(){
                socket.emit('change channel',$("#channel").val());
            });
        });

        socket.on('message',function(msg){

            $('#message').append($('<p><strong>' + '<?echo $_SESSION["user"]?>' + ': </strong>' + msg + '</p>'));

            $('.chat-window').scrollTop($('#message').height());

        socket.on('change channel',function(channel){
            $("#message").html('').append($('<li>').text('system : Bienvenido al Canal '+channel+' !'));
        });
    </script>

    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="chat-window">
              <div id="message"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="controls">

        <form action="" method="post">
            <select name="channel" id="channel">

                <option value="<?echo $codroom?>">Channel A</option>
             <option value="<?echo $codroom?>">Channel B</option>
            </select>

            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="input-group enter-chat-message">
                    <input type="text" id="msg" name="a" class="form-control" placeholder="Chat Message...">
                    <input class="input-group-addon submit-chat-message" type="submit" id="btn" name="submit" value="Enviar">
                </div>
            </div>
</div></div>
        </form>

    </div></div></div></div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
            <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
            <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I tried to get the input form message which it's name="a" with:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
      $aa=$_POST['a'];
      $sql4 = "INSERT INTO as3 (aa1) VALUES('$aa')";
      $resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $sql4); // Realizamos la consulta. mysqli_query() parámetros: conexión, consulta
    }
```

Or below $("form").submit(function(){

tried to get the message in a PHP variable to insert it to the database.

Maybe the thing I try it's easy, but using this with node.js and php it has been a bit difficult because I'm a beginner using node.js

Sorry if my english wasn't perfect,
Hope you can help me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I work on a project like this the best solution i think is you create a uid filed for each user in the database
Keep all the logic's for chat part in NodeJs.
you have to send the message data with WebSocket too.
and the data you have to send might look like this

```
{
 "sender_user_uid" : "nsdasdwq324yhjdasjdh548dwadjkhhdt6@e3",
 "message": "Hello",
 "channel_uid": "hbklierokwe,zcsadkwq324545@%#"
}
```

Comment: and if I want to save it to mysql in php side, getting the message before it arrives in node.js, through input field?

Comment: it is possible to save the message in PHP and then send it from PHP to NodeJs.